# Force fzf :Tags to use a specific file with vim

Tags: vim, tags, project, fzf, vim-fzf

I'm using fzf for a few weeks now and it really changed my workflow. I'm working on a big project with multiple things interconnected.

I'd like to use `:Tags` command to have an overview of all existing tags in the whole project (not to have multiple tags files) in the folder `/home/ctags/` (ctags bin being here).

My command in the vimrc is

```
let g:fzf_tags_command='/home/ctags/bin/ctags -R --extra=+qf --excmd=pattern --exclude=Makefile -f /home/ctags/tags /home/work/project/'
```

Because of something I don't understand, while I use `:Tags`, tags file is generated where I want to, but the error "Failed to create tags" occurs..

The question becomes more simple : how to force fzf to use a specific tag file ?

Bonus
I added

```
set tags=./tags;
set tags+=/usr/include
```

To also include import tags, but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea ?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Found the solution !

This has to be added on top of `.vimrc` file

```
set autochdir
set tags=/home/work/tags,tags;
```

And the command for `:Tags` is

```
let g:fzf_tags_command='/home/ctags/bin/ctags -R -f /home/work/tags --extra=+qf --excmd=pattern --exclude=Makefile /home/work/project/'
```

This way, only one tag file will be generated and it will be updated each time you invoke fzf.